# Does JQuery (div).load recall the (div).load function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which when the div is loaded it executes code:

```
$("#row").ready(function () {
```

When the page has first loaded, it fires fine, my data loads up without any problems.

How ever I would like to reload the div every time the value of a textbox is changed.

```
$("#startDatePicker").change(function () {
    $("#row").load(document.URL);
});
```

Which is why I have that code there.

However when I change it, the .change event is fired, however it doesn't reload my div? Now I'm not sure if the div has been reloaded and it just doesn't fire the event or the event is not being loaded again at all.

EDIT
Thanks to the comment using an alert to check if the div is being called, I found out that is it not being called after I load it, so the next question is, how do I recall the (div).ready function again?

Comment: You can add a callback on load like $("#row").load(document.URL,function(){ alert('Div loaded');}), and see if you get alert.

Comment: Genius... Well that's answered the question that the event is not being fired again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is with jquery-cache.
Try it:

```
$("#startDatePicker").change(function () {
    $("#row").load(document.URL+'?dt='+new Date().getTime(), function() {
           alert( "Load was performed." ); // perform the operations here that 
                                           // that you wish to perform on .ready
      });
});
```

See if it helps.

Comment: I tried and it hasn't done anything, the (div).ready event still isn't firing

Comment: Thanks, not got it working exactly how I want it too but this is defiantly put me onto a better path to getting what I need